# React Native gradle build failed ":app:checkDebugAarMetadata gradlew.bat" "app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081"

Tags: react-native, gradle

When I run 'npm run android' on a new react native project I get this error:

> webtoonreader@0.0.1 android
> react-native run-android

info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 in C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)".
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 in C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.3
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" finished.

> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED                                                                                9 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 5 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
A build operation failed.
Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.
Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. > A build operation failed. Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'. > Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'. * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 11s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I've already tried:

- Reinstalling the lastest node version
- Reinstalling the lastest npm version
- Reinstalling the lastest java version
- Reinstalling the lastest android studio version (made sure to delete the sdks)
- Checking ANDROID_HOME env variable
- Checking ANDROID_SDK_ROOT env variable
- Checking GRADLE_HOME env variable
- Installing all 33.x sdk versions
- Installing the sdk tools versions 29.0.2 / 29.0.3 / 30.0.3 / 33.0.0 / 33.0.1 / 33.0.2 / 34.0.0
- Checking SDK versions
- Clearing npm cache
- Clearing react-native cache
- Updating gradle-wrapper.properties distributionUrl with the correct gradle version
- Deleting node_modules & package-lock.json and running 'npm install'
- Running 'gradlew clean' before running 'npm run android'

Comment: Is the issue resolved?

Comment: No, the only thing I found to fix my problem was to switch from windows to ubuntu which takes care of having everything up to date correctly. Never going back to windows to dev.